# Multi chain wallet provider(EVM + Solana)

Tags: ethereum, solana, ethers.js, solana-web3js, web3-react

I’m trying to find a library or some reference for using both EVM-based wallet provider and Solana Wallet Adapter in a single dApp, but couldn’t find any. If anyone could help me find some references, would really help.

Comment: I am now struggling to setup a repo with both chains and is a pain in the ass. So any leads much appreciated.